# Okta sync with database as identify provider

Tags: okta

We are planning to use Okta as our identity provider and found some resources on its developer site, we was thinking to use Database sync option, we have already number of users on our own database so I want some detailed technical guidance that how we can sync things with Okta and how later we can support SAML 2.0 protocol with other identity providers.

Please provide some detailed things for start point. we are using mysql databases right now.

It would be great support if all technical resources in detail because I dont found enough detailed checklist on side.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have specific questions? This question, as worded, is a bit to vague for SO. Needs code/examples/specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You might start with the On-Premise Provisioning Guide available at:

[Example Setup of On-Premises Provisioning and MySQL](https://support.okta.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/46749316-On-Premises-Provisioning-Deployment-Guide?id=kA0F0000000AY3C&l=en_US&c=Okta_Documentation%3AProvisioning&fs=Search&pn=1#example)

If you get stuck, add a comment to your question or ask a new one.